# Using a file with specific IDs to extract data from another file into separate files and then using them to get values

Tags: bash, parsing, unix, bioinformatics

I have a file with some IDs listed like this:

```
id1
id2
id3 
etc
```

I want to use those IDs to extract data from files (IDs are occurring in every file) and save output for each of these IDs to a separate file (IDs are protein family names and I want to get each protein from a specific family). And, when I have the name for each of the protein I want to use this name to get those proteins (in `.fasta` format), so that they would be grouped by their family (they'll be staying in the same group)

So I've tried to do it like this (I knew that it would dump all the IDs into one file):

```bash
#! /bin/bash

for file in *out
do grep -n -E 'id1|id2|id3' /directory/$file >> output; done
```

I would appreciate any help and I will gladly specify if not everything is clear to you.

EDIT: i will try to clarify, sorry for the inconvenience:

so theres a file called "pfamacc" with the following content:

```
PF12312
PF43555
PF34923
```

and so on - those are the IDs that i need to acces other files, which have a structure like that "something_something.faa.out"

```
<acc_number> <aligment_start> <aligment_end> <pfam_acc>
RXOOOA 5 250 PF12312
OC2144 6 200 PF34923
```

i need those accesion numbers so i can then get protein sequences from files which look like this:

```
>RXOOOA
ASDBSADBASDGHH

>OC2144
SADHHASDASDCJHWINF
```

Comment: Do you want all lines with `id1` into one file, all `id2` into a second file etc? Please [edit] your question and add some example input, the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer a) what you have and b) what you want. At the moment we can only see one of two (?) input files and no expected result. Thank you.

Comment: BTW: Your `grep` command is a substring match. For example, `id1` would also match `otherid123`.

Comment: Hi, i've added an edit to my OP :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading that a list needs to be cross-referenced to get a 2nd list, which then needs to be used to gather FASTAs.

Starting with the following 3 files...

starting_values.txt

```
PF12312
PF43555
PF34923
```

cross_reference.txt

```
<acc_number> <aligment_start> <aligment_end> <pfam_acc>
RXOOOA 5 250 PF12312
OC2144 6 200 PF34923
```

find_from_file.fasta

```
>RXOOOA
ASDBSADBASDGHH
>OC2144
SADHHASDASDCJHWINF
SADHHASDASDCJHWINF
>NC11111
IURJCNKAERJKADSF
```

```
for i in `cat starting_values.txt`; do awk -v var=$i 'var==$4 {print $1}' cross_reference.txt; done > needed_accessions.txt
```

If multiline FASTA change to single line. https://www.biostars.org/p/9262/

```
awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);}  END {printf("\n");}' find_from_file.fasta > find_from_file.temp
```

```
for i in `cat needed_accessions.txt`; do grep -A 1 "$i" find_from_file.temp; done > found_sequences.fasta
```

Final Output...

found_sequences.fasta

```
>RXOOOA
ASDBSADBASDGHH
>OC2144
SADHHASDASDCJHWINFSADHHASDASDCJHWINF
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption there is a file `ids_file.txt` in the same directory with the subsequent content:

```
id1
id2
id3
id4
```

And in the same directory is as well a file called `id1` with the following content:

```
Bla bla bla
id1
and id2
is
here id4
```

Then this script could help:

```
#!/bin/sh

IDS=$(cat ids_file.txt)
IDS_IN_ONE=$(cat ids_file.txt | tr '\n' '|' | sed -r 's/(\|)?\|$//')
echo $IDS_IN_ONE

for file in $IDS; do
 grep -n -E "$IDS_IN_ONE" ./$file >> output
done
```

The file `output` has then the following result:

```
2:id1
3:and id2
5:here id4
```

Comment: Hi, thank You, but its not exactly what I was looking for, I added an edit to my OP :)